# Is contentOffset the right property to determine the scrolling position of the scroll view?

Tags: iphone

I need to get the current scrolling position of an UIScrollView. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the contentOffset property of your UIScrollView that holds the current offset of the content view. Simply add this method to your UIScrollViewDelegate to watch how the value of the contentOffset changes when you scroll:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"contentOffset: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.contentOffset));
}
```